# Queueing Multiple Downloads, looking for a producer consumer API

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, download-manager

I have an application (a servlet, but that's not very important) that downloads a set of files and parse them to extract information. Up to now, I did those operations in a loop : 
- fetching new file on the Internet
- analyzing it.

A multi-threaded download-manager seems a better solution for this problem and I would like to implement it in the fastest way possible.

Some of the downloads are dependant from others (so, this set is partially ordered).

Mutli-threaded programming is hard and if I could find an API to do that I would be quite happy. I need to put a group of files (ordered) in a queue and get the first group of files that is completely downloaded.

Do you know of any library I could use to achieve that ?

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
BlockingQueue<Download> queue = new BlockingQueue<Download>();
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
Download obj = new Download(queue); 
pool.execute(obj); //start download and place on queue once completed
Data data = queue.take(); //get completely downloaded item
```

You may have to use a different kind of queue if the speed of each download is not the same. BlockingQueue is first in first out I believe.

You may want to look into using a PriorityBlockingQueue which will order the Download objects according to their Comparable method. See the **[API here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)** for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was hoping for, some oen who would redirect me to the new thread API... Old school java programmers have to recycle sometimes... :)